# django docker db migrations is not working for the new model

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new here in `django` `docker`.

I have created new model for `django` app, I am working on `docker`. When I am trying to use migrate command `docker exec -ti 75ce87c91dc7 sh -c "python app/manage.py migrate"`, it says: `No migrations to apply`. Here I have added my models.py file, do we need to import this models to anywhere else?

Folder Structure :

[image]

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for trialriskincApi project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xh86wu$_k@g46*+y9v_$2q^jnfg$uc44yh4+15nl2+2dx^$il%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'trialriskincApi',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'trialriskincApi.middleware.open_access_middleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trialriskincApi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trialriskincApi.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'trail_risk_inc_backend',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '12345678',
        'HOST': 'db',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'




# Cors headers

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

models.py

```
 from django.conf import settings
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class  Userprofile(models.Model) :

        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        type = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        updated_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

        def publish(self):
            self.updated_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `No changes detected` that suggests that Django is not discovering your `models.py`, given that you are using the project as your app as well, I am guessing you forgot to add your project name (which is the same as your app name) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

e.g. in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "trialriskincApi",
)
```

Comment: I have added models.py file in same folder as my settings.py file there, can you check my folder structure, i have added that in my question

Comment: What is inside your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: still not getting that model, can you see my folder structure and tell me my model is in correct folder or not

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py` as well?

Comment: i have added it in my question

Comment: There is nothing left more than running `python manage.py makemigrations trialriskincApi` followed by `python manage.py migrate`. If this is still not working, add the whole project to GitHub or so and share a link with me and I can look more into it

Comment: i have added it in github, make sure, project is in docker https://github.com/nikultaka/python-issue

Comment: Tested it in the same explanation as my last comment, works. Not sure how to further help.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate a new model you have to run 
`python manage.py makemigrations <yourAppName>`

And for Docker  you do like this:
`docker exec -ti 75ce87c91dc7 sh -c "python app/manage.py makemigrations <yourAppName>`

Comment: but i am using docker

Comment: Yeah! So you do like this
```docker exec -ti 75ce87c91dc7 sh -c "python app/manage.py makemigrations <yourAppName>```

Comment: it says No changes detected

Comment: Do we need to define that model somewhere else ?

Comment: Did you Import it in models/__init__.py ?

Comment: Can you check my folder structure, i have uploaded image in my question

Comment: I dont think that there is a problem with that structure.
I recommend to separate each Layer in a folder and also add the migrations folder with its init file
migrations/__init__.py

Comment: Should i create new app for that ?